# How do I add a primary key to a column, an existing data table?

Tags: clickhouse

What is the request to add the primary key to a certain column, an existing MergeTree data table?

I tried to change it with a standard query, but it didn't give any results:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ClickHouse, you can't directly add a primary key to an existing MergeTree table column once it has been created. The primary key structure of a MergeTree table is determined at the time of table creation and cannot be altered afterward.

If you need to change the primary key structure for a table, you typically have to follow these steps:

1. Create a New Table: Create a new MergeTree table with the desired primary key structure, including the columns you want in the primary key.
2. Copy Data: Copy the data from the old table to the new table. This can be done using an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... query.
3. Rename or Swap Tables: You can rename the old table or the new table, or you can use ClickHouse's table swap functionality to replace the old table with the new one. Renaming the tables or swapping them depends on your specific use case and requirements.

```
-- Step 1: Create a new table with the desired primary key structure

CREATE TABLE new_table
(
    date Date,
    id UInt64
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY date;

-- Step 2: Copy data from the old table to the new table
INSERT INTO new_table (date, id)
SELECT date, id FROM old_table;

-- Step 3: Swap the tables (replace the old table with the new one)
RENAME TABLE old_table TO old_table_backup, new_table TO old_table;

-- Optionally, you can drop the old backup table if everything is working as expected
DROP TABLE old_table_backup;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2023, it is unfortunately not possible to change the primary key of a table (or add one). Here is the related [discussion](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/147) on GitHub. You would need to [create another table](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table#with-a-schema-similar-to-other-table) with the same schema and the desired primary key and do an [INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/insert-into#inserting-the-results-of-select) from the original table.